# Accessing bulk array values in code behind using Ajax

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am passing values to code behind (C#). I had researched a lot and used this code, but it didn't work for me. Below is the code that I used.

I need to pass values in code behind (C#), but using this code I am getting an error near `routes.EnableFriendlyUrls(settings);` as:

**Script:**

```
<script>
    function foo() {
       var values = ["1,", "2", "3"];

       // Make the Ajax call
       $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "Default.aspx/Done", // the method we are calling
           contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
           data: {values : JSON.stringify({ arr: values })},
           dataType: "json",
           success: function (result) {
               alert('Yay! It worked!');
           },
           error: function (result) {
               alert('Oh no :(');
           }
       });
       return false;
    }
</script>
```

**HTML:**

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button"  UseSubmitBehavior="false" OnClientClick="return foo();" />
    </div>
</form>
```

**Code:**

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        var settings = new FriendlyUrlSettings();
        //settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent;
        routes.EnableFriendlyUrls(settings);
    }
}

[WebMethod]
public static void test(string[] arr)
{

}
```

Though I had an error in code behind, I am not getting any error, and I am unable to go to code behind even after putting the break point. I am getting a button when I run this code, and when I click this not happen except the page is getting refreshed each time when I click the button. How can I do this?

Comment: You are passing integer array hence you should get `int[]` in code behind as well. Change this: `public static void RegisterRoutes(int[] values)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
 var values = [1, 2, 3];//your array wasn't valid 

 data: {values : values},//you don't need to stringify the values because we have a valid json syntax
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.